# MySQL - Converting week of year to days

Tags: mysql, date

It is possible to extract the days included in week of the year?

For example:

2015 Week 2:
The output should:
2015-01-05 AND 2015-01-11

Firstday is Monday.

I search in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html and not found anything.

Comment: MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of data. If there's no data stored then there's nothing to retrieve! Also, are you sure that '2015-01-11' is in Week 1?

Comment: My idea is to store the week number in Mysql and extracts days. Sorry is Week 2; SELECT WEEKOFYEAR('2015-01-05'); AND SELECT WEEKOFYEAR('2015-01-11')

Comment: extract days for what ultimate purpose?

Comment: To show in php, it is better to convert the data in php?

Comment: Thank you very much, I start with it.

Comment: I was doing search and got that post it do the trick 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527166/year-and-week-to-date-in-php