# Why does Carbon::createFromFormat result in an error when used with week format?

Tags: php, php-7, php-carbon

This code:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-W', '2018-11');
```

throws this error:

```
The format separator does not match Trailing data
```

Why does this happen? The string clearly matches with the format, and it works when I use different formats and strings like `'Y-m-d' and '2018-11-11'`. What is wrong with using the week number?

Comment: Datetime class does not support Week number in createfromformat. You can do it by yourself. F.e. using any answer from there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527166/year-and-week-to-date-in-php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php has the formats used by createFromFormat

Comment: @aynber if you post that as an answer I can accept it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage is impossible in PHP (not related to Carbon):

https://3v4l.org/2KjXX

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-W', '2018-11'));
var_dump(\DateTime::getLastErrors());
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(2) {
    [5]=>
    string(35) "The format separator does not match"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "Trailing data"
  }
}
```

apokryfos's suggestion is good. But be careful, the year-week numbers have different meaning depending on cultures (different start of week, start of year). Carbon handle it with `->locale()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using carbon and given that you can't use "W" in the format you can do:

```
$date = Carbon::create(2018)->week(11);
```

Yields date:

> 2018-03-12 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)